# Forked Java VM exited abnormally. JUnit Test?

Tags: java, junit

I have a simple Java program that seems to work well until uploaded to my school's grading system, "WebCat", which I'm assuming is just running JUnit.  The error it kicks back is:

> Forked Java VM exited abnormally. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the >time until the VM exit.

I've researched this issue and and the main first troubleshooting step seems to be to look at the dump log.  Unfortunately I cannot do that in this case. I am really at a loss on how to begin to troubleshoot this considering the lack of feedback from the grading system and the lack of compile or run-time errors.

Here is the code if anyone is familiar with this error or can at least give me some direction of where to begin troubleshooting.  Much appreciated!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;



class PlayerApp {
    public static void showMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("Player App Menu");
        System.out.println("P - Print Report");
        System.out.println("A - Add Score");
        System.out.println("D - Delete Score");
        System.out.println("L - Find Lowest Score");
        System.out.println("H - Find Highest Score");
        System.out.println("Q - Quit");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {   
        if (args.length == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("File name was expected as a run argument.");
            System.out.println("Program ending.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String fileName = args[0];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String stnew = "";
        boolean exit = false;
        Player p = null;
        double[] scoreList;

        File dbFile = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName); 
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(inStream);
       String name = stdin.readLine();
       stnew = stdin.readLine();
       int numScore = Integer.parseInt(stnew);
       scoreList = new double[numScore];
       for (int i = 0; i < numScore; i++)
       {
          stnew = stdin.readLine();
          scoreList[i] = Double.parseDouble(stnew);
       }

       p = new Player(name, numScore, scoreList);

       stdin.close();

        System.out.println("File read in and Player object created.");
       showMenu();
       while (exit == false)
       {

        System.out.print("\nEnter Code [P, A, D, L, H, or Q]:");
        String choice = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        if (choice.equals("p"))
        {
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
        else if (choice.equals("a"))
        {
            System.out.print("   Score to add: ");
            stnew = sc.nextLine();
            double scoreIn = Double.parseDouble(stnew);
            p.addScore(scoreIn);
        }
        else if (choice.equals("d"))
        {
            System.out.print("   Score to delete: ");
            stnew = sc.nextLine();
            double scoreIn = Double.parseDouble(stnew);
            p.deleteScore(scoreIn);
            System.out.println("   Score removed.");
        }
        else if (choice.equals("l"))
        {
            System.out.println("   Lowest score: " + p.findLowestScore());
        }
        else if (choice.equals("h"))
        {
            System.out.println("   Highest score: " + p.findHighestScore());
        }
        else if (choice.equals("q"))
        {
            exit = true;
        }
        }


   }
}
```

break

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;



public class Player {

    //Variables
    private String name;
    private int numOfScores;
    private double[] scores = new double[numOfScores];

    //Constructor
    public Player(String nameIn, int numOfScoresIn, double[] scoresIn) {
       name = nameIn;
       numOfScores = numOfScoresIn;
       scores = scoresIn;
   }

    //Methods
    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
    public double[] getScores() {
       return scores;
    }
    public int getNumScores() {
       return numOfScores;
    }
    public String toString() {

        String res = "";
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#,###.0#");
      DecimalFormat twoEForm = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
        res += "   Player Name: " + name + "\n   Scores: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfScores; i++)
        {
            res += twoDForm.format(scores[i]) + " ";
        }
        res += "\n   Average Score: ";
        res += twoEForm.format(this.computeAvgScore());
        return res;
    }
    public void addScore(double scoreIn) {
       double newScores[] = new double[numOfScores +1 ];
       for (int i = 0; i < numOfScores; i++)
       {
           newScores[i] = scores[i];
       }
       scores = new double[numOfScores + 1];
       for(int i = 0; i < numOfScores; i++)
       {
           scores[i] = newScores[i];
       }
       scores[numOfScores] = scoreIn;
       numOfScores++;
    }
    public boolean deleteScore(double scoreIn) {
        boolean found = false; 
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfScores; i++)
        {
           if (scores[i] == scoreIn)
            {
                found = true;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        if (found == true)
        {
            double newScores[] = new double[numOfScores -1 ];
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
               newScores[i] = scores[i];
            }
            for (int i = index + 1; i < numOfScores; i++)
            {
                newScores[i - 1] = scores[i];
            }
            scores = new double[numOfScores - 1];
            numOfScores--;
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfScores; i++)
            {
                scores[i] = newScores[i];
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }
    public void increaseScoresCapacity() 
    {
        scores = new double[numOfScores + 1];
        numOfScores++;
    }
    public double findLowestScore() {
        double res = 100.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfScores; i++)
        {
            if (scores[i] < res)
            {
                res = scores[i];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    public double findHighestScore() {
        double res = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfScores; i++)
        {
            if (scores[i] > res)
            {
                res = scores[i];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    public double computeAvgScore() {
        double res = 0.0;
      if (numOfScores > 0) {
           for (int i = 0; i < numOfScores; i++)
        {
               res += scores[i];
           }
           return res / (double)(numOfScores);
      }
      else {
         //res = 0.0;
         return res;
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is calling `System.exit(0)` for certain inputs. Don't do that! That's exactly what the message is telling you: that the JVM exited in the middle of the text, before the scoring code could finish up. Instead of calling `exit()`, just use `return` to return from `main()` early.

Comment: Good grief! It's embarrassing to admit the time I wasted on this one small issue. Your time is much appreciated!

Comment: Is this a problem that I can have in real life, or is this just an automated grading issue?  Seems that "exiting" the program is what I wanted to do at that juncture in the program?

Comment: You do actually have to be careful when you call `exit()` in real life. If you're writing `main()` yourself, then go for it, because you're in control. If, on the other hand, you're writing a library that talks to a scanner (just an example), then that library better never, ever call `exit()`, because you don't know what kind of program might be calling you. If I use your library and my program mysteriously quits, I will not be happy!

Comment: System.exit() causes the JVM to shut down right there and now.  You don't normally want to do this in an app except for places like well defined shutdown actions.

Answer (score 1):

The library [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.com/system-rules/) has a JUnit rule called [ExpectedSystemExit](http://stefanbirkner.github.com/system-rules/#ExpectedSystemExit). With this rule you are able to test code, that calls System.exit(...).